# Example 4, Sec. 30, and Example 3, Sec. 31, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: How is this set closed in $\mathbb{R}_l^2$?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, sorgenfrey-line

Let $\mathbb{R}_l$ denote the set of real numbers with the lower limit topology having as a basis the collection of all the closed-open intervals of the form $[a, b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are any real numbers such that $a < b$.

Consider $\mathbb{R}_l^2$ with the product topology having as a basis all the Cartesian products of the form $[a, b) \times [c, d)$, where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are any real numbers such that $a < b$ and $c < d$.

Let $L$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}_l^2$ given by
$$
L \colon= \{\, x \times (-x) \, \colon \, x \in \mathbb{R} \, \}. \tag{Definition 0}
$$

How to show that this set $L$ is closed in the product space $\mathbb{R}_l^2$?

Of course, $L$ is a union of (uncountably many) closed sets.

My Attempt:

> Let $a \times b$ be any point of $\mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L$. Then $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $b \neq -a$. Refer to (Definition 0) above. Thus either $b < -a$ or $b> -a$.

> Case 1. Suppose that $b < -a$. Let $p$ be any real number such that
> $$
> b < p < -a. \tag{1}
> $$
> Then we of course have
> $$
> a < -p < -b. \tag{2}
> $$

> Now consider the basis set $[a, -p) \times [ b, p)$ for the topology of $\mathbb{R}_l^2$ containing the point $a \times b$.

> If $x \times y \in [a, -p) \times [b, p)$, then we find that
> $$ a \leq x < -p, $$
> and
> $$ b \leq y < p. $$
> the first of these two relations implies
> $$
> p < -x,
> $$
> and hence we obtain
> $$
> y < p < -x,
> $$
> which implies that $y \neq -x$, and so $x \times y \in \mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L$. Therefore we have
> $$
> [a, -p) \times [b, p) \subset \mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L. 
> $$

> Case 2. Now suppose that $b > -a$. Then $-b < a$. Let $p$ be any real number such that
> $$
> -b < p < a. \tag{3}
> $$
> Then we also have
> $$
> -a < -p < b. \tag{4}
> $$

> Now consider the basis set $[a, a+1) \times [b, b+1)$ for the product topology on $\mathbb{R}_l^2$.

> Let $x \times y$ be any point of $[a, a+1) \times [b, b+1)$. Then we have
> $$
> a \leq x < a+1, \tag{5}
> $$
> and
> $$
> b \leq y < b+1. \tag{6}
> $$

> From (3) and (5) we obtain
> $$
> p < x,
> $$
> and hence
> $$
> -x < -p. \tag{7}
> $$
> Now from (4) and (6) we obtain
> $$
> -p < y,
> $$
> which together with (7) implies
> $$
> -x < -p < y,
> $$
> and hence $y \neq -x$, which shows that $x \times y \in \mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L$. Therefore
> $$
> [a, a+1) \times [b, b+1) \subset \mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L.
> $$

> Thus in either case we find that, for any point $a \times b$ of the set $\mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L$, there exists a basis set $B_{a \times b}$ for the product topology on $\mathbb{R}_l^2$ such that
> $$
> a \times b \in B_{a \times b} \subset \mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L.
> $$

> Thus $\mathbb{R}_l^2 \setminus L$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}_l^2$. Hence $L$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}_l^2$.

Is this proof correct? If so, is my presentation correct and clear enough too? Or, are there any issues?

Can we somehow reduce Case 2 in my proof to a without any loss of generality argument following Case 1?

Comment: The proof is ok, but the notation $a\times b$ for a point in $\mathbb R^2$ instead of the usual $(a,b)$ is not quite right.

Comment: @Sam That's Munkres' doing, in order to distinguish intervals from ordered pairs (I am not advocating for it's usage). See page 13 of the 2014 edition.

Comment: @Sam this is the notation used by Munkres, as has been pointed out in an earlier comment. Actually, I quite like this notation for it enables one to distinguish ordered pairs from open intervals defined using an order relation on a Cartesian product of sets.